# How to stop ng-option duplication repeat in Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, ng-options

**Angular JS Select for filter**

I have a create a search module which is able to search with input type text.. now i want to add select option in form to search filter it

Here is the Plunker : http://embed.plnkr.co/yPJADtUDcgU720dx8ChJ/preview

Comment: Your select box ng option data is wrong try putting {{search.category}} in your html and see that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the categories from the json, then removing the duplication:

```
//Filter all the categories, return an array of duplicated categories
var allCategories = json.modules.map(function(item) {
  return item.category;
});

//Remove the duplication from the first array
var filteredCategories = [];
allCategories.forEach(function(item) {
  if (filteredCategories.indexOf(item) < 0) {
    filteredCategories.push(item);
  }
});

//Assign the filtered array to scope
$scope.categories = filteredCategories;
```

Change the html too:

```
<select ng-model="search.category" ng-options="category for category in categories"></select>
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z6IUMTzePO7UoWoGuUfP?p=preview

Comment: How to populate the same category list items to Checkbox options.. so i can select more than one at a time

Comment: The checkbox is a little complicated, I don't have a clean solution. You can try asking another question to get everyone's answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ng-model="**search**" like this:

```
<select ng-model="search" ng-options="module.category for module in ocw.modules"></select>
```

Link demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/U0DudD80VIf0ExKh5ixO?p=preview